# Не могу написать sql запрос c AGE и AVG

Tags: sql

У меня есть SQL запрос, который получает время ответа на задачу.

(вычисляется как : время создания задачи - время комментария)

```
select jiraaction.author,actionbody,  jiraissue.pkey, age (jiraaction.created, jiraissue.created)as time_response
from jiraaction 
inner join jiraissue on jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
where jiraissue.pkey like '%-26578%'
```

Проблема в том, что дальше я не могу применить функцию - "AVG" (для того чтобы вычистить среднее время ответа. )

Как эти функции правильно сопоставить ? ("AGE" И "AVG")